# Loading images from Server Blazor client-side

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have been testing out Blazor client-side for a few days now and have gotten a file upload system to work, but when I try to load the image from the server in an `"<img src="~/uploads/images/file1.jpg">"` html tag from the client the image fails to load. The server is running as a Project on 
https://localhost:5001
and the client is running in IISExpress mode on
https://localhost:44306

I suspect what is happening is the image is trying to load from the Client project port rather than the Server project port. How can I get all image requests to be routed to the server address where the images are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your project was in production today, is it accurate that they would be hosted on two separate sites? (e.g. myblazorapp.com and api.myblazorapp.com). If so, then the relative path will only be kicking the can down the road. Use configuration to store the fully qualified path to the images directory.

However, if your server-side code was created for the purpose of this Blazor app, then you might have picked the wrong [hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The `Hosted` model allows you to use an ASP.NET core app to server the Blazor app to the client. It also means that the server's resources, apis, and static files will all be available via relative urls.

Comment: I was over looking the obvious fact that the api calls were done to a different URL, but I did start the project as Hosted model so I figured they would have had access to server files.